# Is there a way for copying posts telegram channels and then send that to others channels using telegram bot?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telegram-bot

I want to make a telegram bot for aggregating posts from multi channels and after that send that posts to other channels.is it possible? I'm using asp.net `MVC` and `webhook` method.

Comment: why give me negative point? did you have a good reason for that?

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but I believe that you'd better show what you have so far tried.

Comment: @WeijunZhou,I want to know just is it possible copy posts telegram channels and then send that to other channels is there a way for that?that's it.